# Quadtree is not subdividing properly C++ SFML

Tags: c++, structure, sfml, quadtree

I am creating a quadtree with C++/SFML. and I am having trouble with finding the faults in my program. I have been trying for weeks however I really can't find the fault, and I don't really have any friends who know C++.

Upon the insertion of points into the quadtree, it is not subdividing correctly. Another additional problem is that my program only seems to work in Release mode and not in Debug mode.

**Boundary.h:**

Boundary.h represents the AABB for each quadrant within the quadtree. I have inherited from sf::RectangleShape just for visualisation. I have also inhertited from sf::FloatRect so I can use the bool sf::FloatRect::contains() functionality, which returns a bool as to whether a point(sf::Vector2f) lies within the Rectangle.

```
#ifndef BOUNDARY_H
#define BOUNDARY_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

struct Boundary : sf::RectangleShape, private sf::FloatRect
{
    Boundary(const sf::Vector2f& centre, const sf::Vector2f& halfsize);
    sf::Vector2f centre;
    sf::Vector2f halfsize;
    using sf::FloatRect::contains;
};
#endif
```

**Boundary.cpp:**

The sf::FloatRect::FloatRect() constructor takes in the top left of the rectangle, and its full size.
In my quadtree however, it is easier to think about the boundaries based on their centres, and halfsizes, hence why `sf::FloatRect(centre - halfsize, halfsize + halfsize)`

```
#include "Boundary.h"
Boundary::Boundary(const sf::Vector2f& centre, const sf::Vector2f& halfsize)
    :sf::FloatRect(centre - halfsize, halfsize + halfsize), centre(centre), halfsize(halfsize)
{
    this->setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);
    this->setOutlineColor(sf::Color::White);
    this->setOutlineThickness(1);
    this->setPosition(centre);
    this->setOrigin(halfsize);
    this->setSize(halfsize + halfsize);
}
```

**Quadrant.h**

This represents a Quadrant in the quadtree.

```
#ifndef QUADRANT_H
#define QUADRANT_H
#include "Point.h"
#include "Boundary.h"
#include <iostream>
struct Quadrant : Boundary
{
    int firstChildindex; //stores the index of its first child. since the children are contiguous in the base array, you can find them by firstchild + i while 0<=i<4
    Point* firstpointnode = nullptr; //stores the beginning of a point list which are all in this current quadrant.
    int count = 0; //-1 if the quadrant is a branch / subdivided
    Quadrant(const Boundary& AABB);
    void subdivide(std::vector<Quadrant>& m_quadrantStorage); //splits the quadrant into four children.
    bool insert(Point* pointnode, std::vector<Quadrant>& m_quadrantStorage);
};  
#endif
```

**Quadrant.cpp:**

```
#include "Quadrant.h"
#include "Globals.h"
#include <iostream>
Quadrant::Quadrant(const Boundary& AABB)
    :Boundary(AABB)
{

}
bool Quadrant::insert(Point* pointnode, std::vector<Quadrant>& m_quadrantStorage)
{
    if (!this->contains(pointnode->position)) return false; //if the point isnt within this boundary, forget about it.
    else if (count < QCAPACITY && count!= -1) //otherwise if it is contained, and it isnt full and isnt a branch, we can insert to the end of the point list.
    {
        if (firstpointnode == nullptr) {
            firstpointnode = pointnode;
            firstpointnode->next = nullptr;
        }
        else {
            Point* currentpointnode = firstpointnode;
            while (currentpointnode->next != nullptr) //traversing to the end of this quadrant point list
            {
                currentpointnode = currentpointnode->next;
            }
            currentpointnode->next = pointnode; // currentpointnode is the last node in the list by this point.
            currentpointnode->next->next = nullptr; //disassociating any ties that the point had with any other points, so it is the absolute end of the list.
        }
        count++;
        return true;
    }
    else if (count != -1) //or if the point is within the quadrant, is full, and it hasnt already subdivided, subdivide.
    {
        subdivide(m_quadrantStorage);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (m_quadrantStorage[firstChildindex + i].insert(pointnode, m_quadrantStorage)) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
void Quadrant::subdivide(std::vector<Quadrant>& m_quadrantStorage)
{
    sf::Vector2f newhalfsize = halfsize / float(2);
    firstChildindex = m_quadrantStorage.size();//children are contiguous in memory - nth child = firstChildindex + n for 0<=n<4
    m_quadrantStorage.emplace_back(Boundary{ sf::Vector2f { centre.x + newhalfsize.x, centre.y - newhalfsize.y }, newhalfsize });
    m_quadrantStorage.emplace_back(Boundary{ sf::Vector2f { centre.x + newhalfsize.x, centre.y + newhalfsize.y }, newhalfsize });
    m_quadrantStorage.emplace_back(Boundary{ sf::Vector2f { centre.x - newhalfsize.x, centre.y + newhalfsize.y }, newhalfsize });
    m_quadrantStorage.emplace_back(Boundary{ sf::Vector2f { centre.x - newhalfsize.x, centre.y - newhalfsize.y }, newhalfsize });
    Point* currentpointnode = firstpointnode;
    while (currentpointnode->next != nullptr) //transferring all points from parent list to children.
    {
        Point* nextpointnode = currentpointnode->next;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            m_quadrantStorage[firstChildindex + i].insert(currentpointnode, m_quadrantStorage);
        }
        currentpointnode->next = nullptr;
        currentpointnode = nextpointnode;
        nextpointnode = currentpointnode->next;
    }
    firstpointnode = nullptr; // this parent does not have a point anymore, so it is nullptr.
    count = -1; //this parent is no longer a leaf, it is a branch, so the count is now -1.
}
```

**Quadtree.h**

This handles all of the active quadrants and can be thought of as the engine.

```
#ifndef QUADTREE_H
#define QUADTREE_H
#include "Quadrant.h"
#include "Point.h"
#include <vector>
#include <random>

class Quadtree
{
public:
    Quadtree(sf::RenderWindow* winptr);
    void display() const;
    void debug();
    bool insert(Point* point);
    Point* constructPoint(const sf::Vector2f& pos);
    static sf::Vector2f randomPoint();
private:
    sf::RenderWindow* m_winPtr = nullptr;

    std::vector<Quadrant> m_quadrantStorage;
    std::vector<Point*> m_pointStorage;
    sf::VertexArray verticies;

    std::vector<int> findleaves(const Boundary& rect);

    static std::mt19937 m_randomEngine;
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<float> m_uniform;
};
#endif
```

**Quadtree.cpp**

```
#include "Quadtree.h"
#include "Globals.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
Quadtree::Quadtree(sf::RenderWindow* winptr)
    :m_winPtr(winptr)
{
    m_quadrantStorage.emplace_back(Boundary{ sf::Vector2f{0.0f,0.0f}, sf::Vector2f{WIDTH / 2,HEIGHT / 2} });

}
void Quadtree::display() const
{
    for (const auto& q : m_quadrantStorage)
    {
        m_winPtr->draw(q);
    }
    m_winPtr->draw(verticies);
}
std::vector<int> Quadtree::findleaves(const Boundary& rect) //I AM NOT USING THIS FUNCTION FOR NOW!!
{
    std::vector<int> leaves, to_process;
    to_process.push_back(0);
    while (to_process.size() > 0)
    {
        int index = to_process.back();
        auto node = m_quadrantStorage.begin() + index;
        to_process.pop_back();

        if (node->count != -1)
        {
            leaves.push_back(index);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                to_process.push_back(node->firstChildindex + i);
            }
        }
    }
    return leaves;
}
bool Quadtree::insert(Point* point)
{

    m_quadrantStorage[0].insert(point, m_quadrantStorage);
    return true;
}
void Quadtree::debug()
{
    //Quadrant& root = m_quadrantStorage[0];
    //root.subdivide(m_quadrantStorage);
    //m_quadrantStorage[root.firstChildindex].subdivide(m_quadrantStorage);

}
Point* Quadtree::constructPoint(const sf::Vector2f& pos)
{
    Point* newPoint = new Point(pos);
    m_pointStorage.push_back(newPoint);
    verticies.append(*newPoint);
    insert(newPoint);
    return newPoint;
}


std::mt19937 Quadtree::m_randomEngine(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> Quadtree::m_uniform{ -WIDTH/2,WIDTH/2 };
sf::Vector2f Quadtree::randomPoint()
{
    return { m_uniform(m_randomEngine), m_uniform(m_randomEngine) };
}
```

**Point.h**
This represents a node as part of a singly linked list, containing the pointer to the next node, and its element value (its position).

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
struct Point : sf::Vertex
{
    Point(const sf::Vector2f& pos);
    Point* next = nullptr;
};

#endif
```

***Point.cpp***

```
#include "Point.h"

Point::Point(const sf::Vector2f& pos)
    :sf::Vertex(pos)
{
}
```

***Source.cpp***

Contains int main()

```
#include "Globals.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Quadtree.h"
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), "Quadtree Spatialisation", sf::Style::Default);
    sf::Vector2f mousepos;
    sf::View screen{ sf::Vector2f{0,0}, sf::Vector2f{WIDTH,HEIGHT} };
    window.setView(screen);
    sf::VertexArray arr;
    Quadtree QT(&window);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {

        sf::Event evnt;
        while (window.pollEvent(evnt))
        {
            switch (evnt.type)
            {
                case sf::Event::EventType::Closed:
                {
                    window.close();
                }
                case::sf::Event::EventType::MouseMoved:
                {
                    mousepos = static_cast<sf::Vector2f>(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window));
                    mousepos = window.mapPixelToCoords(static_cast<sf::Vector2i>(mousepos));
                }
                case::sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed:
                {
                    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::W))
                    {
                        screen.zoom(0.99);
                        window.setView(screen);
                    }
                    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::S))
                    {
                        screen.zoom(1.01);
                        window.setView(screen);
                    }
                    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Space))
                    {
                        QT.constructPoint(QT.randomPoint());
                    }
                }
                case sf::Event::EventType::MouseButtonPressed:
                {
                    if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
                    {
                        QT.constructPoint(mousepos);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        window.clear();
        QT.display();
        window.draw(arr);
        window.display();

    }
}
```

Comment: I have a look at this. Why are you storing the boundaries as floats?

Comment: Do you mean why am i storing them as sf::Vector2f?